# Derivation of this modified taylor series where we dont need to go to infinite differentiable condition.

Tags: taylor-expansion

I encountered this here, where they did taylor expansion centered around 0 and 2, as we can see only upto third derivative its expanded not more , is there any site or any paper where the proof is given as the (usual taylor series is infinite expansion where there is no condition forced on x to be lying between somewhere.).P.S. i know the derivation for usual taylor expansion    [image]

Comment: These formulas are covered in many texts on calculus.

Comment: Sir any link/pdf pls ? As i only know the proof of the normal taylor expansion , and whats this expansion called ?  "Modified Taylor expansion " or something else i could search on net

Comment: You can read [these notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-2-applications-of-differentiation/part-c-mean-value-theorem-antiderivatives-and-differential-equations/session-34-introduction-to-the-mean-value-theorem/MIT18_01SCF10_ex34sol.pdf) for example or [these](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-075-advanced-calculus-for-engineers-fall-2004/lecture-notes/lecture8.pdf) with proofs.

Comment: Ty Sir :):):):)